# Ropes, cables, hawsers?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, british-english

I am looking for synonyms to 'thick rope' and have found "hawser" and "cable".

However, lexical sources claim that hawsers are for naval use (mooring; towing). Would it seem odd to use "hawser" in another context? (btw, is a hawser a thick rope or a very thick rope?)

Also, I have heard that "cable" connotes a cable of steel. If that is correct, how strong is the connotation? Could ”cable” be used for a hemp rope as well (my concern here is readers’ perceptions)?

Comment: You can consult a good dictionary to see the various meanings of [cable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cable): strong/thick rope, metal rope, bundle of conductors, telegram... The connotations are going to depend on your audience - electrical engineers will have a different sense of what a "cable" is than sailors.

Comment: Yes, *hawser* is more specific than *cable* (maybe, a hawser is a *type* of cable)? I don't know that there's anything wrong, especially to the layman, with sticking with "thick rope."

Comment: Re *"is a hawser a thick rope or a very thick rope?"* Given that a [hawser](https://www.lexico.com/definition/hawser) is used to moor or tow a ship, I'd go for 'very thick'.

Comment: See the [illustrations](https://www.google.com/search?q=hawser&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwimxabW0-P0AhUPXlMKHbryANUQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=hawser&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQ6BwgjEO8DECc6BAgAEAM6CAgAEIAEELEDOgQIABBDOgsIABCABBCxAxCDAVDACVicEmCrE2gAcAB4AIABUYgBoQSSAQE3mAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWfAAQE&sclient=img&ei=ob64YebwFY-8zQK65YOoDQ&bih=529&biw=933&rlz=1C1CHBD_enUS911US911) for *hawsers*. Some are quite thick.

Comment: Voting to close.  Please show us how you want to use the word. / I had never heard of hawsers.